# How to integrate an AWS Lambda function to Trigger an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rest-api

What option should I pick for [Azure DevOps Rest API Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) and why?

I tried PATs as an authentication method, but it does not fit for a **long-lived integration** "30 days is the maximum expiration"

what is the best practice to authenticate this AWS Lambda function to trigger [the azure-pipelines REST-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0), with less operations and more security